# Getting the value in float even though input value is integer

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am reading the data from Google spread sheet using Google app script.
in one of the cell(sprint version) of spreadsheet I have mentioned the value as 56 but when I am reading the value it is returning 56.0. I don't know why

Below method, I wrote to read the value from spreadsheet

```
function readAndSetTimePeriodMetaData() {
  var timePeriodArray = new Array();
  var masterSheetID = "My Google Sheet ID";
  var masterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheetID);
  var timePeriodDataSheet = masterSheet.getSheetByName("Time Period MetaData");
  data = timePeriodDataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var range = timePeriodDataSheet.getRange(1,2);
  var sprintVersion = range.getValue();  //it is returning 56.0
  var range = timePeriodDataSheet.getRange(2,2);
  var monthValue = range.getValue();
  var range = timePeriodDataSheet.getRange(3,2);
  var quarterValue = range.getValue();
  Logger.log(sprintVersion)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using toFixed(0)

```
var sprintVersion = range.getValue().toFixed(0);
```